# Using := with j in data.table (workaround for unimplemented feature)

Tags: r, data.table

Edit: This problem was due to an outdated version of data.table being installed.

I have a data.table like the following:

```
require(xts)
a <- data.table(colour=c("Red","Green","Blue","Blue","Black","Black"), date=c(as.Date("2011-07-04"),as.Date("2011-07-10"),as.Date("2011-07-09"),as.Date("2011-07-12"),as.Date("2011-07-04"),as.Date("2011-07-09")),daily.quantity=c(1,-1,2,-2,1,1))

     colour       date daily.quantity
[1,]    Red 2011-07-04              1
[2,]  Green 2011-07-10             -1
[3,]   Blue 2011-07-09              2
[4,]   Blue 2011-07-12             -2
[5,]  Black 2011-07-04              1
[6,]  Black 2011-07-09              1
```

I would like cumulative totals per colour, to look like this:

```
     colour       date daily.quantity cumulative.quantity
[1,]  Black 2011-07-04              1                   1
[2,]  Black 2011-07-09              1                   2
[3,]   Blue 2011-07-09              2                   2
[4,]   Blue 2011-07-12             -2                   0
[5,]  Green 2011-07-10             -1                  -1
[6,]    Red 2011-07-04              1                   1
```

However, if I try the following, I end up with cumulative totals that don't take colour into account:

```
setkey(a,colour,date)
a[,cumulative.quantity := cumsum(daily.quantity)]

     colour       date daily.quantity cumulative.quantity
[1,]  Black 2011-07-04              1                   1
[2,]  Black 2011-07-09              1                   2
[3,]   Blue 2011-07-09              2                   4
[4,]   Blue 2011-07-12             -2                   2
[5,]  Green 2011-07-10             -1                   1
[6,]    Red 2011-07-04              1                   2
```

I tried the obvious, but unfortunately unimplemented:

```
> a[,cumulative.quantity := cumsum(daily.quantity),keyby="colour,date"]
Error in `[.data.table`(a, , `:=`(cumulative.quantity, cumsum(daily.quantity)),  : 
  Combining := in j with by is not yet implemented. Please let maintainer('data.table') know if you are interested in this.
```

So, can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `by` grouping should only be on `colour`:

```
a[,cumulative.quantity := cumsum(daily.quantity), by=colour]
   colour       date daily.quantity cumulative.quantity
1:  Black 2011-07-04              1                   1
2:  Black 2011-07-09              1                   2
3:   Blue 2011-07-09              2                   2
4:   Blue 2011-07-12             -2                   0
5:  Green 2011-07-10             -1                  -1
6:    Red 2011-07-04              1                   1
```

Comment: Does this code run for you? I receive the 'not implemented' error above.

Comment: @Ina Yes, this code works fine. I have version 1.8.2 of `data.table`.

Comment: Thank you, I needed to upgrade my version. But you're right, I should have grouped on colour rather than both - I hope I would have noticed that if I wasn't hitting errors :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not want totals by 'date' and 'colour', only by 'colour'. Not sure why you required xts, since data.table is in pkg:data.table.

```
> a[,cumulative.quantity := cumsum(daily.quantity), by=c("colour") ]
   colour       date daily.quantity cumulative.quantity
1:  Black 2011-07-04              1                   1
2:  Black 2011-07-09              1                   2
3:   Blue 2011-07-09              2                   2
4:   Blue 2011-07-12             -2                   0
5:  Green 2011-07-10             -1                  -1
6:    Red 2011-07-04              1                   1
```

If you did actually wnat by two columns (which would imply that your "want-to-look-like-this" example is wrong, you could do this:

```
> setkey(a,colour,date)
> a[,cumulative.quantity := cumsum(daily.quantity), by=c("colour", "date") ]
   colour       date daily.quantity cumulative.quantity
1:  Black 2011-07-04              1                   1
2:  Black 2011-07-09              1                   1
3:   Blue 2011-07-09              2                   2
4:   Blue 2011-07-12             -2                  -2
5:  Green 2011-07-10             -1                  -1
6:    Red 2011-07-04              1                   1
```